# bitbucket permission denied (public key) when git pull

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-pull

I get the following error when I try to pull from bit bucket. I'm in an AWS ECS instance:

```
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have already added the ssh key to the bit bucket account access keys and have tried adding the key to my repository itself. Earlier I have successfully pushed my code to bit bucket but never did a pull.

Answer (score 0):

Try first one of the methods listed in "[Troubleshooting SSH connections to AWS CodeCommit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ssh.html)"

In bash, you can do:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v" git pull
```

That will show you which shs key Git is using for that operation: you can check its public key is indeed the one you have set in your AWS account/ECS instance.